# Installing netbeans on Scientific Linux- NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"

Tags: software-installation, environment-variables, display, display-settings, ide

I'm installing netbeans 8.0.1 on Scientific Linux. I have executed the installer .sh but I get the error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the
>   UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"

I found this bug report:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=213437

which suggests the problem is I haven't set my display environment variable before the GUI installer appears. In my bash rc I did:

> export DISPLAY=local_host:0.0

re-sourced it but the problem still doesn't go away. I am on multiple monitors. Could somebody please help?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the same exception as in the error? Have you compared the log files? Also the environment variable should read `DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` (without the underline character.

Comment: I'm assuming your running a Desktop Environment at the time of the attempt? Usually I get an error like that when there's no X server/session running.  If there's a DE, all of that is taken care of in the background.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing netbeans as root, your problem may be due to X not allowing root access to the session (this was the case when I initially attempted to install).  The following web page gives a number of different ways to give the root user access to the current X session and also briefly discusses the security issues:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Running_X_apps_as_root

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I was trying to run the installer in root. I noticed the information in answer 1, I ran the installation in standard user in console the GUI opened right up and 8.1 installed no issues. Once you CHMOD the file there's no need to be in root to install it.